# Is adding multiple rules to css using insertRule() possible?

Tags: javascript, css

Hi this is the HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Theme.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <textarea id="ta" onpaste="functionItalic(event)" class="foostyle2"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 20px;">
        <span id="1">Karan's</span>
     </span>
    <span style="font-weight: bolder; font-size: 24px; font-style: italic;">test</span>
</div>
<script>
function functionItalic(pasteEvent)
{
var textareacont = (pasteEvent.originalEvent || pasteEvent).clipboardData.getData("text/html");
console.log(textareacont);
var styleSheetList = document.styleSheets;
document.getElementById("1").className = "foostyle";
var stringCSS = ".foostyle{font-family: Times-Roman;font-size:10pt;color:rgb(0,0,0);font-style:normal;}";
styleSheetList[0].insertRule(stringCSS, styleSheetList[0].cssRules.length);

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this file everything works fine and style gets added.

But as soon I as change the value of stringCSS to

```
var stringCSS = ".foostyle{font-family: Times-Roman;font-size:10pt;color:rgb(0,0,0);font-style:normal;} .foostyle2{background: green;}";
```

The browser provides an error

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified
styleSheetList[0].insertRule(stingCSS, styleSheetList[0].cssRules.length);
```

What am I missing is adding multiple classes/rule through insertRule not possible or I have done some mistake? please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) states that

> If more than one rule is given in the rule parameter, then aborts with
>   SyntaxError

So what is a rule, the specification also says that a rule is

> ... a DOMString containing the rule to be inserted, ...where rule
>   specifies selector and declaration, or at-identifier and rule content.

So it's a string with a *"selector and a declaration"* of styles, in other words a rule is

```
.selector {declaration : of_styles}
```

or with the *"at-identifier and rule content"*

```
@font-face { font-family: 'font'; src: local('font'), url(/font.ttf); }
```

You're passing it

```
.foostyle{font-family: Times-Roman;font-size:10pt;color:rgb(0,0,0);font-style:normal;} 
.foostyle2{background: green;}
```

which is two rules, and it aborts with a syntax error, as expected.

To solve it, you have to call `insertRule()` twice, once for each rule

Comment: Thanks @adeno Is there any other way then calling insertRule again and again?

Comment: sure, you load another stylesheet instead, or use classes to change styles, it's very rare to ever need to modify the stylesheets.